# File Not Found when viewing Files on the Repository Browser

Tags: git, bonobo

I am using Bonobo Git Server with form authentication. When i trying to view a file from the repository browser its showing 404 Error. 
If it tried to access README.md file

```
URl : http://localhost/gitscm/Repository/helloworld/Blob/master/README.md
```

404 Error is showing.

```
Requested URL
http://localhost:80/gitscm/Repository/helloworld/Blob/master/README.md 

Physical Path
E:\usr\scm\Bonobo.Git.Server\Repository\helloworld\Blob\master\README.md
```

I have verified permission for IUSR it has rights.